# understanding Band Properties of Arbitrary Response Filter in FilterBuilder

Tags: matlab, filter

I would like your help to understand the inputs of Frequencies and Amplitudes, of the Band Properties Panel.

So I open filterbuilder, select the Arbitrary Response Filter. In the Main tab I set Impulse Response to FIR, Order of 200 and Filter Type Single-rate. In the Response Specifications the number of bands is 1, I have specified the response as Amplitudes and the Frequency units are set to Hz. I set the Input Fs equal to 44100Hz.

I assign some values to the appropriate vectors Frequencies and Amplitudes, but I get an error saying that "the Frequencies vector must be monotonically increasing."

I guess what I'm asking is what do the vectors Frequencies and Amplitudes serve as? What should their size be?

BTW, I am running R2010b.

Comment: What you are entering, there, is the [frequency response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_response) of the filter. The amplitudes represent the magnitude of the response *at the corresponding frequency*. As the error says, the frequencies must be monotonically increasing, which means `[1 2 3 4 5]` is valid but `[1 3 2 4 5]` is not.

Comment: so it's the same as when I have plot(time,x) where frequency is time and x is amplitude

Comment: Erm... well those are the axes of a plot of the frequency magnitude response of a system, yes, but it's not the same as a plot of the time history of some data... If you don't actually understand what a frequency response is then I suggest you read up on the topics of "frequency domain", "frequency response", and "Fourier analysis". There are literally thousands of resources that will explain it much better than I can.